# Replacing with pattern on built-in symbols?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, built-in-symbols

I have:

```
f[a, b] /. f[x__] -> g[x, 0] // InputForm
(* Out: g[a, b, 0] *)
```

Which is what I expect, but when I use a built in symbol instead of `f`, the result is different, for example:

```
Times[a, b] /. Times[x__] -> g[x, 0] // InputForm
(* Out: g[a*b, 0] *)
```

How could I replace the multiplication in this case to get the same result as above?

Comment: Use Verbatim or HoldPattern, e.g., `Times[a, b] /. Verbatim[Times][x__] -> g[x, 0]` or `Times[a, b] /. HoldPattern[Times[x__]] -> g[x, 0]`

Comment: You could try `Times[a, b] /. Times[x___, y__] :> g[y, 0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amplifying my comment. The issue you are encountering is that a single argument [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) evaluates *(it has nothing to do with the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) attribute of [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times))*:

```
Times[x__]
```

> x__

Hence, your code is actually doing:

```
Times[a, b] /. x__ -> g[x, 0]
```

> g[a b, 0]

The way to avoid this is to prevent evaluation of the LHS pattern, with the typical methods being to use [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim):

```
Times[a, b] /. Verbatim[Times][x__] -> g[x, 0]
```

> g[a, b, 0]

or to use [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern):

```
Times[a, b] /. HoldPattern[Times[x__]] -> g[x, 0]
```

> g[a, b, 0]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that `Times` is a built-in symbol. As explained in another answer it stems from the evaluation of the `Times` in the LHS of the rule. My previous explanation (see edit) was wrong and misleading.

Having said that, one way to make it work is to simply replace the `Head`

```
In[1]:= a b /. Times -> (g[##, 0] &)
```

> Out[1]:= g[a, b, 0]

If you have more complicated replacement rules you can always replace `Times` with a new symbol e.g. `newTimes`, make it `Orderless` if needed and then apply the rules to `newTimes`.

Comment: The problem is actually an evaluation issue and not a Flat pattern matching issue.

Comment: You are completely right, sorry.