# Pattern matching repeated arguments of Times

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to match against products of elements with a specific pattern. Since a product of symbols `A B C` is just `Times[A,B,C]`, I figured this could be done by treating `Times` like any other symbol (here `f`):

```
MatchQ[ f[a,b,c], f[_Symbol..] ]
>>> True
```

Woe, such a pattern doesn't seem to work for `Times`:

```
MatchQ[ a b c, Times[_Symbol..] ]
>>> False

MatchQ[ Times[a, b, c], Times[_Symbol..] ]
>>> False
```

I suspect this may be due to some property of `Times` related to its commutativity, though there's no auto-commuting in this example!

```
a b c // FullForm
>>> Times[a, b, c]
```

How can I produce the desired pattern for matching repeated-pattern arguments of `Times`?

Comment: Related: [(156282)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156282), [(191133)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191133), [(194131)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194131)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need wrap the pattern `Times[...]` with [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html)  or [`Verbatim`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim.html) to prevent `Times[_Symbol ..]` evaluating to `_Symbol..` before `MatchQ` does its work:

```
MatchQ[a b c, HoldPattern[Times][_Symbol ..]]
```

> True

```
MatchQ[a b  c, Verbatim[Times][_Symbol ..]]
```

> True

```
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], HoldPattern[Times][_Symbol ..]]
```

> True

```
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], Verbatim[Times][_Symbol ..]]
```

> True